# Facing issue in designing *PROMOCODE* DB schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Working on new application DB schema design. In that application there is a promo-code option for users. I'm facing problem or may be I'm confused in designing promo-code table and its working. I have created table with following attributes.

Restricted_Promos table is a promocode for specific users only.

```
PromoCode:                                                         
name
description
status
valid_from
valid_til
discount
max_usage
created_at
created_by
updated_at
updated_by 

Restricted_Promos:
PromoCodeId
UserId
Count
```

Scenarios in which i'm facing problem is that:

- How one promocode can by used by multiple users? And how to track
  them like who used and how many time the single promocode is used?
- If a promocode is for specific user and for single time usage how to 
  should be it manage in that?
- Is this promocode schema is flexable?    Like in future if i have to
  add promocode based on some outsider    company promotion like bank.
  Will it work for that too.

Answer (score 1):

I would rename `Restricted_Promos` to `Assigned_Promos`. Then I would create a new table:

```
Promo_Usages:
PromoCodeId
UsedBy
UsedAt
```

Now you know who and how many times used a promo.

To manage max usage number, I suggest to add trigger on `Promo_Usages` and compare `count(PromoCodeId)` with `PromoCode.max_count`. By the way, I strongly suggest you use one naming convention. Now you're mixing several.

This schema is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just move the common fields to PromoCode and add a Purpose:

```
PromoCode:                                                         
name
description
status
valid_from
valid_til
discount
created_at
created_by
updated_at
updated_by
Purpose
MaxUsageCount
UsedCount

PromoCode2User:
PromoCodeId
UserId
```

Now you can handle personal Codes ("join PromoCode2User on PromoCodeId...") and codes usable by multiple persons ("not in select PromoCodeId from PromoCode2User..."). All Codes have a MaxUsageCount and a currently UsedCount. Using the Purpose field, you can store the name of the promotion campaign or define internal categories, so you can easily revoke or change Codes on bulk later.

As for PromoCodeUsed, track that in a separate table. And yes, I'd track the usage per user and in total separately. You might need to do that to handle the case where a promocode can be used by unidentified users or you want to be able to delete users and still retain count of all uses of the code.

```
PromoCodeUsed:
PromoCodeId
UserId
Count
```